# Configure window in App Delegate with TabBar and NavBar

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I'm not totally sure how to phrase this, but for some reason I'd assume its fairly simple. The below is code that works for a NavigationBar and a ViewController to set up the managed context/core data in my App Delegate (under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions). How do I make the same thing work but with a TabBar as well (assuming I still want to get to the UIViewController)?

```
let navController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
let viewController = navController.topViewController as! ViewController
viewController.coreDataStack = coreDataStack
```

The below was my attempt at doing this, but it errors out with the "tabController.selectedIndex = 2" command.

```
let tabController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
let navController = (tabController.selectedIndex = 2) as! UINavigationController
let viewController = navController.topViewController as! FamilyViewController
viewController.coreDataStack = coreDataStack
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think let navController = (tabController.selectedIndex = 2) as! UINavigationController is not correct.

tabController.selectedIndex = 2 instead of that you should use [tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]

Sorry for not using swift syntax but I think you can get the idea from that.

Comment: Perfect! For reference for anyone else, it ended up being tabController.viewControllers![1] when finally converted to Swift. Thanks so much!